# simplemodal close link with class

Tags: simplemodal

I want to have a modal box with default (x) image in the corner and also a text link to close modal box. I put a class to a element like so: simplemodal-close but it is not working. The link is inside the element that is copied inside modal box. At last I created jquery script to call closing function upon element click but without any effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.simplemodal-close-test').click(function () {
$.modal.close();

})
});
```

Can anybody help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event to live.  This did the trick for me.

```
$('#frmprocessing .closeit').live('click', function(e) {
    $.modal.close();
    return false;
});
```